# Is there a way to determine if com.sforce.async.BulkConnection is thread-safe?

Tags: bulk-api, sforce

Is there a way to determine if com.sforce.async.BulkConnection is thread-safe?
I'm unable to find any documentation regarding thread safety of the connection objects.
So help to determine thread safety of **com.sforce.async.BulkConnection** and **com.sforce.soap.enterprise.EnterpriseConnection**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API itself has limitations on multithreading, as I've stated in a [previous answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/13499/2984). The generated clients may or may not be thread safe depending on the language you're using. The reason why the documentation has nothing to say about it has to do with the fact that each language generates webservice code from a WSDL in language-dependent ways. You would need to examine the code directly to determine if it is thread-safe or not. It's been quite a long time since I've written anything in Java, but I distinctly recall that SOAP clients were generally not thread safe with regards to login/logout session changes. However, it should also be trivial to fix them up to make them thread-safe.